# Old values not appearing when editing PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am doing a library system. A librarian can view all the books, and may choose to edit a book and it's details. However, when I click edit, the values do not show up in the input field.

This is my edit portion of the code. I am getting an error:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable on line 7

which is `if (count($record) == 1 ) {`:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE BookNo='$BookNo'");
    if (count($record) == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
        $BookNo = $n['BookNo'];
        $ISBN = $n['ISBN'];
        $title = $n['title'];
        $author = $n['author'];
        $publisher = $n['publisher'];
        $status = $n['status'];
        $cost = $n['cost'];
    }
}
?>
```

This is my displaying of the data for the librarian, along with the edit button:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['BookNo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ISBN']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['publisher']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cost']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="viewBook.php?edit=<?php echo $row['BookNo']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
        </td>
```

Followed by, the fields in which the librarian can edit the details.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) { ?>
<form method="post" action = "viewBook.php">
<input type="hidden" name="BookNo" value="<?php echo $BookNo; ?>">
<input type="text" name="ISBN" value="<?php echo $ISBN; ?>">
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $author; ?>">
<input type="text" name="publisher" value="<?php echo $publisher; ?>">
<input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $status; ?>">
<input type="text" name="cost" value="<?php echo $cost; ?>">
<?php if ($update == true): ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="update" style="background: #556B2F;" >update</button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>
<?php endif ?>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

When I click the edit button, I get the error stated above, as well as the text fields not having the details already written inside.

Comment: var_dump($record); .... mysqli_query returns a mysqli_result object : http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: A librarian (or someone walking past) can also `drop tables` or `drop databases` due the the SQL injection vulnerability you have.

Comment: Check the docs for [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), they show that it returns either `false`, or a `mysqli_result` object for a SELECT query. They also show how to check how many rows were returned.

Comment: insufficient information to give correct and useful answer, please elaborate more

Answer (score 1):

count() function only works with arrays and other countable fields
use the [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp)

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE BookNo='$BookNo'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($record) == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
        $BookNo = $n['BookNo'];
        $ISBN = $n['ISBN'];
        $title = $n['title'];
        $author = $n['author'];
        $publisher = $n['publisher'];
        $status = $n['status'];
        $cost = $n['cost'];
    }
}
?>
```

this **mysqli_num_rows** can give you result of the count of amount of data from sql query

I think this will work for you.

Comment: This seems to get rid of the error. Thank you! Do you know a solution for the 2nd part? The fields are not having the values copied over.

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli_fetch_assoc()

So, I am doing a library system. A librarian can view all the books, and may choose to edit a book and it's details. However, when I click edit, the values do not show up in the input field.

This is my edit portion of the code. I am getting an error:

count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on line 7

which is if (count($record) == 1 ) {:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE BookNo='$BookNo'");
    if (count($record) == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record);
        $BookNo = $n['BookNo'];
        $ISBN = $n['ISBN'];
        $title = $n['title'];
        $author = $n['author'];
        $publisher = $n['publisher'];
        $status = $n['status'];
        $cost = $n['cost'];
    }
}
?>
```